# Как в Datagrid каждые два элемента коллекции разместить в одной строке? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Нужно отформатировать Datagrid таким образом, чтобы ход белых и последующий ход черных находился в одной строке, но при этом, они были бы в разных ячейках. Соответственно следующие два хода на следующей строке, и т.д.[image: Что имею сейчас.]
В коде ничего особенного. DataGrid берет данные из коллекции, в которую последовательно записываются ходы в виде строк. 
Казалось бы простая задачка, но как сделать не представляю. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: А коллекция из каких элементов у вас? Напишите класс `Ход`, в котором будет два свойство — полуход белых и полуход черных. Храните в коллекции экземпляры этого класса. Остальное — дело техники

Comment: Дело в том, что в коллекции на каждый полуход, я еще храню положение доски в формате FEN, чтобы можно было отрисовать доску на предыдущие полуходы, поэтому тут тоже сложности.

Comment: Ну так создайте ещё одну коллекцию, как я вам написал. Я гарантирую, что это будет сильно проще, чем городить что-то с DataGrid